# Fitting probability distributions based on moment generating functions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, moment-generating-functions

Say I have a random variable $X$ with mgf

$M_X(t) = 1 + a_1t + a_2t^2 + a_3t^3 + \cdots $

and another random variable $Y$ with a probability distribution determined by two parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, and with mgf

$M_Y(t) = 1 + b_1(\theta_1,\theta_2)t + b_2(\theta_1,\theta_2)t^2 + \cdots $

Suppose I want to fit the parameters of the random variable $Y$ to the random variable $X$, i.e. I want to find $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ so that the distribution of $Y$ most closely approximates the distribution of $X$. What is the best way to do this solely by comparing the two mgfs?

My thinking so far:

The method of moments, for example, would try to solve

$b_1(\theta_1,\theta_2) = a_1\quad$ and $\quad b_2(\theta_1,\theta_2) = a_2$

(provided these equations uniquely determine $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$). However, this can lead to large errors in higher order moments. One could otherwise try a least-square fit by choosing $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ that minimize

$\sum_{i=1}^{K} |b_i(\theta_1,\theta_2) - a_i|^2$

for some large $K$. My question here is whether it is better to closely fit a small number of lower order moments, or is it better to choose a large $K$ in order to spread out the fitting error across many moments? Is there some theory in statistics that studies such problems?

Answer (score 0):

The following paper seems that it could help you,
[Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/272264)

but it is behind a paywall so I could only see the abstract.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple method that'll still improve your method you might watch the following video about a generalization of the method of moments (GMM):
[Generalised Method of Moments Estimation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLJqjiI0aHM)

Briefly, you can define the following error function:

$$ g_i = b_i(\theta_1,\theta_2) - a_i$$
$$e = \sum_{i=1}^{K} w_i|g_i|^2$$

Where $w_i$ are positive weights. For example, you might normalize the moments-errors as in:

$$ w_i = \frac{1}{Var(g_i)} $$

Assuming you're trying to fit Y to multiple observations of X, so $a_i$ has a variance. You might also give more weight to lower moments as in:

$$ w_i = q^i $$
for some positive $ q < 1 $. or 
$$ w_i = \frac{1}{i} $$

As a more general case, It's suggested to estimating the covariance matrix $W$ of the moments-error $g_i$, and use:

$$ e = g_i^TWg_i $$

[GMM Implementation on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments#Implementation) describes how to compute W.

You might be interested in reading (it is behind a paywall):

[The weighted method of moments approach for moment condition models](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176510000200)